Recreating vignette with rmarkdown failed for 'R Under Development'
I need to build an R package for 'R Under development' (4.5.0) which could be built without problems for R 4.4.0. However, now I get the error:

creating vignettes ... ERROR
--- neu erzeugen von 'ocs-vignette.Rmd' mit rmarkdown Exited with status 1.

Or alternatively:

checking re-building of vignette outputs ... [19s] ERROR
Error(s) in re-building vignettes:
--- re-building 'ocs-vignette.Rmd' using rmarkdown

Does anyone know why the error message appears? It occurs only with 'R Under development', on different machines.
The problem is partly solved: The error has nothing to do with rmarkdown. The R Devel version handles my c++ code differently than R.4.4, which causes R to abort during the creation of the vignette.
However, the problem remains: How differ R devel and R 4.4.0 in handling c or c++ code?
